# Kpatch in Ubuntu Proper

Tags: reboot, patch, canonical-livepatch

I noticed that there is a [kpatch](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kpatch) packages being maintained and it appears to be available for Xenial and Yakkety. Is there a plan to start releasing kernel patches as kpatch patches? Will we get Live Kernel patching "soon" (TM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical Live Patch was just announced today for 16.04:

- http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/10/canonical-livepatch.html
- https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch

This uses the live patching technology in the upstream Linux kernel since 4.0 was released.